# How to join my "clients" and "messages" tables?

Tags: mysql

There are two tables:

```
Clients
___________
idClient int
login varchar

Messages
___________
idMessage int
dateWakeup datetime
.... other fields
```

I need for each client to count the number of entries in the table Messages in a given range of time. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT c.login, count(m.idMessage) FROM Clients c, Messages m
where
    m.idClient=c.idClient and m.dateWakeup>'2010-09-01 00:00:01'
    and m.dateWakeup<'2010-10-01 00:00:01';
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `COUNT(...)`, you have to `GROUP BY` your results:

```
SELECT c.login, count(m.idMessage)
FROM Clients c, Messages m
where m.idClient=c.idClient
and m.dateWakeup>'2010-09-01 00:00:01'
and m.dateWakeup<'2010-10-01 00:00:01'
GROUP BY c.login
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
SELECT c.login, count(m.idMessage) FROM Clients as c
INNER JOIN Messages as m
ON m.idClient=c.idClient
WHERE m.dateWakeup BETWEEN '2010-09-01 00:00:01' and '2010-10-01 00:00:01'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.login, count(m.idMessage) FROM Clients c, Messages m  
where m.idClient=c.idClient and m.dateWakeup>'2010-09-01 00:00:01' and
m.dateWakeup<'2010-10-01 00:00:01' GROUP BY c.login;
```

Aggregate functions such as COUNT() requires a GROUP...BY